# How to mass-produce a pre-made computer image with hardware?

Tags: linux, deployment, imaging

I've created a product running on Linux that I'd like to be able to mindlessly "image", then drop onto similar computer systems. I was hoping you guys could help me with the following:

1. Is there a service online that accepts a disk image and allows you to order computers with that image pre-loaded? Do they do drop shipping?
2. Is there a better approach for cloning most of a system that I can automate to ensure I have minimal involvement in the process? Right now I am picturing imaging, but if our hardware set changes due to factors outside our control, alternatives would be nice.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How many images are we talking about and over what period?

Comment: If you just want an easy way to create repeatable installs, I'd check out chef and/or puppet.

Comment: Dell offers this service, or at least they used to

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an online service that would allow buying PCs pre-built with your image.

As far as an imaging solution, and to avoid physically having to use a flash drive or other removable medium, I'd look into setting yourself up a Fog server (www.fogproject.org). Using an imaging server like that would allow you to mass image large quantities of PCs/servers at a time.

Answer (score 0):

In similar suitation I just create bootable flash that contain image of Linux + plus my software. It boots, then automaticaly install Linux and my soft. Special engineer insert this flash into new machine, wait beep signal after that test basic functionaliy.